# Existe algum método mágico para ao chamar um atributo como método no php?

Tags: php

Por exemplo,
temos a classe:

```
class foo
{
var $bar = 1;
}
```

queria saber se tem como executar algo se eu chamar assim:

```
$foo = new foo;
$foo->bar();
```

Comment: E qual a finalidade de chamar uma propriedade como metodo?

Comment: Um mágico nunca revela seus truques

Comment: @NeuberOliveira faz todo sentido, a pergunta é válida. Frameworks como o Laravel fazem isso, e é bom "desmistificar" isso pra ele (minha resposta). Quando você usa um Pattern chamado `Fluent Interface`, pode ser totalmente válido fazer como o AP está perguntando.

Comment: @BernardoKowacic digamos que eu então fui o Mister M...

Comment: Mister W, o mágico de ponta cabeça.

Comment: @bigown ainda bem que não é "Mister Catra"

Comment: Na verdade o que eu quis dizer, foi o que ele prentedia fazer com isso, saber o cenario dele e qual problema ele pretende resolver com isso.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O método mágico `__call` faz isso.

Veja:

```
class Foo {

      protected $bar;

      public function __call($method, $arguments) {
           return isset($this->$method) ? $this->$method : null;
      }
 }
```

## Para que serve o `__call`?

O método `__call` vai executar uma ação quando você chamar um método de uma classe que não esteja declarado ou seja inacessíveis (`protected` e `private`, por exemplo).

É necessário sempre declarar dois parâmetros para essa função: O primeiro é o nome do método que você tentou invocar, e o segundo, os argumentos passados (esses estão armazenados num `array`).

## Recomendações

Eu recomendaria você manter um padrão para utilizar tais "funcionalidades mágicas". Por exemplo, você sempre detectar se o método que você tentou chamar começa com a palavra `get`.

Veja:

```
class Foo {

      protected $bar = 'bar';

      public function __call($method, $arguments) {

            if (substr($method, 0, 3) == 'get')
            {
                $prop = strtolower(substr($method, 3));

                return $this->$prop;
            }


            throw new \BadMethodCallException("Method $method is not defined");

      }
 }
```

Assim, quando você acessasse o método `getBar`, você obteria o valor de `$bar`.

```
  $foo = new Foo;

  $foo->getBar(); // Retorna 'bar'
```

**Nota**: Se tivéssemos declarado o método público `bar` na classe `Foo`, o valor retornado seria diferente, pois o método existe (e é um método `public`), então `__call` não seria invocado.

```
  public function bar() {

      return 'Valor do método, não da propriedade';

  }
```

## Acréscimo

É altamente recomendado não usar a palavra chave `var`, uma vez que na versão 5 do PHP foi introduzir as palavras chaves de visibilidade `public`, `protected` e `private`, quando for declarar a visibilidade de um método.

Comment: Não só metodos não declarados, mas para metodos inacessiveis tambem, ou seja, se a instancia chamar um metodo protegido ou privado tambem vai cair no `__call`

Comment: Obrigado por lembrar.

Comment: Boa resposta! +1