# Utilização de métodos em orientação a objetos php

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Olá, tenho a seguinte dúvida:

Neste exemplo:

```php
class produtos
{
    public categorias = [];
}
```

categorias é um vetor, como podem perceber. Sua estrutura é a seguinte:

```php
$categorias["tvs"][0] = "aqui o modelo da tv"; 
$categoria["pcs"][0] = "aqui o nome do pc";
```

Eu queria saber como criar um método para alimentar este vetor identificando a categoria pelo método. Exemplo:
Quero adicionar uma TV em tvs assim:

```php
$this->tvs()->add("nome da tv");
```

Já um pc seria da seguinte forma:

```php
$this->pcs()->add("nome do pc");
```

Eu já vi isso em prática em alguns plugins, porém não faço ideia de como fazer. Vocês podem me dar uma ajuda? Espero ter conseguido explicar mais ou menos a ideia...

**Obs.: preciso que add() seja um método pois utilizarei vários parâmetros.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Se você não sabe os nomes das categorias antes de elas serem criadas, você pode utilizar o método [__call](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) para deixar a criação dinâmica.

Um exemplo:

```php
class Categorias
{
    protected $name;
    private $prod;

    public function __construct($name, $prod)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->prod = $prod;
    }

    public function add($value)
    {
        $this->prod->categorias[$this->name][] = $value;
    }
}

class Produtos
{
    public $categorias = array();

    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        return (new Categorias($name, $this));
    }
}

$p = new Produtos();
$p->tvs()->add("teste");
$p->pcs()->add("nome do pc");

var_dump($p->categorias);
```

No código acima, criamos uma classe chamada `categorias`, que basicamente vai ser responsável por preencher o vetor de categorias da classe `produtos`.

O método `__call` é utilizado quando algum método não existente do objeto é chamado. Ou seja, quando as categorias, que você não conhece ainda, são chamadas, o método `__call` é invocado e então repassamos a chamada para uma nova instância da classe `categorias`.

Caso você saiba quais categorias podem ser utilizadas, a segunda opção do @WallaceMaxters funcionaria bem: Enviando as categorias existentes no construtor da classe `produtos` e adicionando uma verificação dentro do `__call` para checar se a categoria existe antes de repassar a responsabilidade.

Traduzindo para forma que escrevi:

```php
class Categorias
{
    protected $name;
    private $prod;

    public function __construct($name, $prod)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->prod = $prod;
    }

    public function add($value)
    {
        $this->prod->categorias[$this->name][] = $value;
    }
}

class Produtos
{
    public $categorias = array();

    public function __construct($categorias = [])
    {
        foreach ($categorias as $categoria) {
            $this->categorias[$categoria] = [];
        }       
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($name, $this->categorias)) {
            // retorna erro.
        }
        return (new Categorias($name, $this));
    }
}

$p = new Produtos(["tvs", "pcs"]);
$p->tvs()->add("teste");
$p->pcs()->add("nome do pc");

var_dump($p->categorias);
```

A classe `categorias` recebe como segundo argumento em seu construtor a instância da classe `produtos`, pois caso precise utilizar alguma propriedade do produto para executar as ações dentro do `add`, terá o objeto disponível para tal.

Comment: Pensamos quase a mesma coisa, hehe. +1

Answer (score 3):

Para fazer tal ação acima, seria necessário que `tvs` e `pcs` retornassem um `objeto` que teria o método `add`.

## Primeira opção

Não sei se seria o mais indicado você utilizar um método só para retornar um objeto que faça isso, mas talvez fosse interessante definir um método para cada ação.

Veja:

```php
class Produtos
{
    public categorias = [
        'tvs' => [],
        'pcs' => []
    ];

    public function addTv($tv)
    {

        $this->categorias['tvs'][] = $tv;
        return $this;
    }

    public function addPc($pc)
    {
        $this->categorias['pcs'][] = $pc;    
        return $this;
    }
}

$produtos = new Produtos;

$produtos->addPc('positivo');
$produtos->addTv('lg');
```

## Segunda opção

Para fazer exatamente do jeito que você quer, você teria que ter um outro objeto responsável por armazenar os dados. Nesse caso, vou nomear as classes de maneira mais adequada para separar as responsabilidades.

Veja:

```php
class Produtos
{
    protected $produtosCategorias = [];

    public function __construct(array $categorias = [])
    {
        foreach ($categorias as $categoria) {
            $this->produtosCategorias[$categoria] = new ProdutosCategoria($categoria);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Usamos o call para acessar os índices do array como se fosse método
     * 
     * */
    public function __call($nomeCategoria, $argumentos)
    {
        if (isset($this->produtosCategorias[$nomeCategoria])) {
            return $this->produtosCategorias[$nomeCategoria];
        }
        throw new \BadMethodCallException("Método {$nomeCategoria} não existe");
    }
}


class ProdutosCategoria
{

    protected $nomeCategoria;
    protected $produtos = [];

    public function __construct($nomeCategoria)
    {
        $this->nomeCategoria = $nomeCategoria;
    }

    public function add($produto)
    {
        if (in_array($produto, $this->produtos)) {
            throw new UnexpectedValueException('Produto já foi adicionado');
        }

        $this->produtos[] = $produto;
        return $this;
    }
}

$produtos = new Produtos(['tvs', 'pcs']);

$produtos->tvs()->add('LG');
$produtos->pcs()->add('Positivo');
```

Dê uma olhada aqui para saber mais sobre o método `__call`:

- [Existe algum método mágico para ao chamar um atributo como método no php?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/151675/4995)

Outras referências:

- [O que é encadeamento de métodos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105259/encadeamento-de-m%C3%A9todos)

Comment: Não sou adepto de métodos 'preguiçosos' (rs) pra esse caso - prefiro a primeira opção. Como garantia usaria `class Produtos implements Aparelhos`.