# Montando uma query com laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Estou estudando a estrutura do laravel a partir desse exemplo já pronto => [bestmomo](https://github.com/bestmomo/laravel5-5-example).

No projeto existe o repositório `userRepository` com a seguinte estrutura:

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;

use App\Models\User;

class UserRepository
{
    /**
     * Get users collection paginate.
     *
     * @param  int  $nbrPages
     * @param  array  $parameters
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator
     */
    public function getAll($nbrPages, $parameters)
    {
        return User::with ('ingoing')
            ->orderBy ($parameters['order'], $parameters['direction'])
            ->when (($parameters['role'] !== 'all'), function ($query) use ($parameters) {
                $query->whereRole ($parameters['role']);
            })->when ($parameters['valid'], function ($query) {
                $query->whereValid (true);
            })->when ($parameters['confirmed'], function ($query) {
                $query->whereConfirmed (true);
            })->when ($parameters['new'], function ($query) {
                $query->has ('ingoing');
            })->paginate ($nbrPages);
    }
}
```

Essa estrutura faz uso do arquivo de config `parameters`:

```
<?php

return [

    'users' => [
        'order' => 'created_at',
        'direction' => 'desc',
        'role' => 'all',
        'valid' => false,
        'confirmed' => false,
        'new' => false,
    ],
    'posts' => [
        'order' => 'created_at',
        'direction' => 'desc',
        'new' => false,
        'active' => false,
    ],
    'contacts' => [
        'new' => false,
    ],
    'comments' => [
        'new' => false,
        'valid' => false,
    ],

];
```

A estrutura do banco de dados é a seguinte:

```
Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->string('name')->unique();
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->enum('role', array('user', 'redac', 'admin'));
    $table->boolean('valid')->default(false);
});
```

Estou tentando entender esses métodos: `whereRole`, `whereValid` e `whereConfirmed`, procurei em todo o projeto e não achei a estrutura desses métodos, como o Laravel monta esses métodos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso é uma das coisas legais (e confusas do Laravel).

Estes métodos não existem, eles são versões curtas do método `where`, aquilo que vem depois desta *keyword* é o nome da coluna que faz parte do `where`.

Ou seja,

```
$query->whereRole('algumValor')
```

é exatamente a mesma coisa que

```
$query->where('role', 'algumValor')
```

> como o Laravel monta esses métodos?

Isso já foi respondido em: [Existe algum método mágico para ao chamar um atributo como método no php?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151674/18246)

Comment: Bacana!! E no caso de uma coluna do banco que for id? Como eu montaria esse where? `whereRole_Id`?

Comment: @MarceloBoni Como assim? `role` já é uma coluna.

Comment: Nesse template já pronto, eles utilizam `role` como um campo enum, eu penso em desacoplar e criar uma nova tabela no bd, referenciando apenas o id do role, nesse caso a coluna `role` passara a ser: `$table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();`

Comment: @MarceloBoni neste caso você troca o snake_case por camel case. Ficaria **`whereRoleId()`**